# Why is JavaScript randomly adding '/1' to the end of URL bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox

So, me and a few friends are making a video game (text adventure) in JavaScript. In this game, you go around fighting monsters. It opens with a fight, but when you win, it randomly adds '/1' to the end of the URL. This is strange because `window.location` never appears in the program. Here is the code that is executed at the time of the problem:

```
function Places() {
location = 1
  answer = prompt('Where do you go now? You have ' + totalGold + ' gold, and ' + hitPoints + ' health.', 'Town, Plains, Swamp, Menu').toUpperCase()
  switch (answer) {
    case 'TOWN':
      if (aabeaDestroysTown === 0) {
        alert('You walk into town, where there is a marketplace and an inn.')
        InTown()
      } else {
        alert('As you near the outskirts of town, you notice the stream of people leaving town. Then you notice that the entire place is now just a gigantic blast crater. Somebody blew it up!!! You decide to investigate, and walk over to the stream of people.')
        alert('When you reach the people, they all say this person named A\'Abea had just come to town and started fires all over, and then used some weird, magical powers to blow up Smatino.')
        alert('You are sure this A\'Abea is the same as the one who you met in the swamp, and wish you had used some \'weird, magical powers\' to blow him up')
        alert('You race back to the swamp, and see him from a distance. You can\'t, however, blow him up. There are too many vines in the way. So, you follow him. You see a large tower in the distance, and finally, after a few hours, reach it at night. You see A\'Abea enter, and then, as the gate is clanging down above him, you slide under it and manage to get in.')
        inTower()
      }
      break;
```

etc. You only see the `prompt()` box for a split second, then it does the random addition.

#### Error Message:

```
/*
Exception: out of memory
*/
```

What is even stranger about this is that it seems to only do it when testing in Firefox.

Comment: Really, you didn't notice the `location = 1` variable at the top of your code, in the global scope *(no "var")*? Change the name of that variable, and it's solved.

Comment: Or at least make it a `var location`.

Comment: the `var location` is at the very top

Comment: _"the `var location` is at the very top"_ At the top of what? Certainly not at the top of the example you posted.

Comment: The very begginning of the code

Comment: oh wait I think I forgot to add that thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're setting `window.location` to `1`. Don't do that unless you want to update the page URL.

By default, variables are set on the global `window` object. If you'd like to set a local variable named `location` inside your function, use `var location = 1`.